# I cannot run rails s because of Json gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I was hopping to get some help because I can't run my project. I added an API to my rails project using serializer and Json, but the thing is when I run rails S I got this error on console. I already tried the following

- Bundle
- Bundle install
- Rebuild all gems
- Removing and adding Json file to Gem File
- Removing all JSON entries from Gemfile.lock

.

```
 home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- jsonapi/include_directive (LoadError)
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/active_model_serializers.rb:50:in `require'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/active_model_serializers.rb:50:in `<module:ActiveModelSerializers>'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/active_model_serializers-0.10.6/lib/active_model_serializers.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
            from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
            from /home/leandro/Documents/ruby/rails/bookstore/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/leandro/Documents/ruby/rails/bookstore/bin/rails:9:in `require'
            from /home/leandro/Documents/ruby/rails/bookstore/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
            from /home/leandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
            from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
            from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
            from /home/leandro/Documents/ruby/rails/bookstore/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
            from bin/rails:3:in `load'
            from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Could you share a bit more about your Rails Version? Perhaps show your Gemfile?

Comment: copy the code of GEmfile .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `bundle exec rails s`